# Next.js redirect all paths except one

Tags: next.js

I want to create a redirect for all subroutes /a, /b, /c but **not** /api.

So my basic setup looks like this:

```
{
  source: '/:path*',
  destination: 'https://otherdomain.com/:path*',
  permanent: false
}
```

What do I have to change to stop redirecting `/api/*` from here?

I tried some hacks like `:path(?!api$)*` but none of them are working.

Answer (score 5):

You can try with regex.

In documentaion is a small example [nextjs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects#regex-path-matching)

In this [github issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/15712) is a example as well.

This regex match everything expect api.

```
^(?!.*\bapi\b).*$
```

In source probably its loks like that.

```
 source: '/:host(^(?!.*\bapi\b).*$)/:path*',
 destination: 'https://otherdomain.com/:host/:path*',
```